# deleterow ie8 problem

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

When I delete the first row in a html table, IE8 leaves a blank line at the end of the table (after the footer).

I use the method: `objTable.deleteRow(objRow.rowIndex);`

My table uses the tag elements: thead, tbody, tfoot.

Comment: What Javascript library are you using? I don't believe `deleteRow` is an actual Javascript function...

Comment: @Topher: `deleteRow` is a [DOM method](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/level-one-html.html#ID-64060425).

Comment: @Helen - Well how bout that...I didn't expect that to be part of the DOM. Guess I should read that soon.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using YUI? If so, you may be interested in checking out http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/dt_rowadddelete.html and use their example to see if you encounter the same issues in your browser. If you do, it's probably IE8 issue (most likely,) or a YUI issue.

You may also be interested in trying out something such as jQuery. Much more light weight, and is pretty much cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reset class of table and set up it again (with [prototype js](http://prototypejs.org/), but you can do it by hands):

```
// Hack. ie8 leaves a blank line at the end of the table, when delete the first row in a html table.
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604183/deleterow-ie8-problem
if (Prototype.Browser.IE && ROW_YOU_DELETE_INDEX == 0) {
    YOUR_TABLE.removeClassName('YOUR_TABLE_CLASS_NAME')
              .addClassName('YOUR_TABLE_CLASS_NAME');
}
```